# Salvar tab-pane ativa ao atualizar a pagina

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

Possuo uma estrutura de duas abas, e preciso que ao atualizar a página a aba ativa continue como ativa. Pensei em fazer uma função click que salva na sessão o id da aba aberta, porém preciso enviar uma requisição (ajax) do js pra Session. Dá pra fazer, mas queria saber se tem uma forma melhor pra fazer isso.

Comment: Olá guilherme, você já produziu algum código em relação a esta questão? Poderia postá-lo?

Comment: Boa tarde Ricardo. Na verdade fiquei só com a lógica na cabeça, porque no meu ponto de vista essa minha solução seria uma "gambiarra". Então queria ver se alguém que passou por isso surge com uma solução melhor que a minha.

Comment: Bom, eu acredito que existem outras solução possíveis, uma delas é um cookie, o problema é que ele é transmitido para o servidor a cada request, o que provavelmente não é desejável. Ainda tem alternativas como o Web SQL, mas acho que seria um canhão para matar uma mosca.

Comment: Você já tentou mudar a url via javascript quando o cara clica na tab? quando ele dê o reload, vai ser com a url que você alterou, `exemplo: seusite.com.br/#tab-pane2`, faço algo parecido no [meu site](http://arpadesign.com.br/#!portfolio/ditesta)

Comment: Rapaziada, implementei minha lógica aqui e funcionou. Obrigado pela colaboração.

Answer (score 0):

Quando preciso de algo desse tipo utilizo essa biblioteca [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

A sintaxe é bem simples:

Criar:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Ler:

```
$.cookie('name');
```

Excluir:

```
$.removeCookie('name');
```

Espero que ajude, abraço.